# insert into table2 select from table1 if the whole row not exists in table2

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-insert, linked-server

my question is:
I have 2 sql server, I am using a linked server to update table on server2 from server1.
I'm using this query:

```
 insert into   [server2].[db2].[dbo].[pcodes] (parcode,pname,unit,typ) select parcode,pname,unit,typ from [server1].[db1].[dbo].[pcodes] where not exists (select parcode,pname,unit,typ from  [server2].[db2].[dbo].[pcodes])
```

the code only works when the table is empty on the server2, so when I excute the query for the first time it works, but after that when I add new record on server1 and execute the query, I am getting (0 rows effected) . any suggestions plz?
I want you to know that I want to update the server2 table if the new or edited record in server1 is not exists in server2.
thanks anyway guys.
UODATE:

[image]

check the image above, when the records were 9 records in server1 and the table empty in server2, the query worked and all the 9 records has been inserted into server2, after that, I added a new record in server1 which is the 10th record, and I excuted the above query, I got (0 rows effected). why the new record not inserted?

Comment: share table structure and possible sample data for which it is worked

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Within the not exist statement you need to have a where condition, your query is missing that,

```
         INSERT INTO   [server2].[db2].[dbo].[pcodes]  (parcode,pname,unit,typ) 
              SELECT parcode,pname,unit,typ 
              FROM [server1].[db1].[dbo].[pcodes] a 
              WHERE NOT EXISTS 
              (SELECT parcode,pname,unit,typ from  [server2].[db2].[dbo].[pcodes] b
              WHERE a.parcode=b.parcode and a.pname=b.pname and a.unit=b.unit and a.typ=b.typ )
```